# How to generate Apple like passes for Google Pay App using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, android-pay, passkit, google-pay

Recently I created a web application using Node js to generate Apple passes just like Passkit (https://www.passkit.com) do and its working perfect but now I have to do the same for Google Pay app. After searching a lot I found the documentation of Google Pay API for Passes (https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/) but the problem is this service is not available for India region, So, can't able to signup in order to consume Google Pay API for pass creation.
I believe it would be possible because Google also provide the same functionality of passes like Apple do but not sure how I could do it in India .

Please do let me know if is it possible or not in India.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You are at the mercy of Google with regards to availability in India. At [PassNinja](http://passninja.com), we are launching a product soon that'll allow for creating Google Pay and Apple Wallet passes which you will be able to use to prototype your idea prior to availability in India. You'll be able to read and decrypt them with an NFC reader.

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](http://www.flomio.com), the company behind PassNinja.